# Print Mqtt topics and Choose one to subscribe to one of them

Tags: java, android, mqtt, paho

I was struggling an issue , the issue was about showing available  mqtt  topics from broker server in multiple textviews in android, and choose one of them  to  subscribe to topics

```
    final MqttAndroidClient client =new MqttAndroidClient(getApplicationContext(),"tcp://iot.eclipse.org:1883","12d45454");
    try {

        client.connect(mqttConnectOptions, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken mqttToken) {

                DisconnectedBufferOptions disconnectedBufferOptions = new DisconnectedBufferOptions();
                disconnectedBufferOptions.setBufferEnabled(true);
                disconnectedBufferOptions.setBufferSize(100);
                disconnectedBufferOptions.setPersistBuffer(false);
                disconnectedBufferOptions.setDeleteOldestMessages(false);

                Log.i("ERROR ","Topic="+mqttToken.getTopics());
                textview1.setText(mqttToken.getTopics()[0]);

            }
```

Comment: It really isn't clear what you are asking here, but there is no where to get a list of topics that messages may be published on. Topics only really exist at the instant a message is published, then the broker checks to see if there is a client with a matching topic pattern and delivers the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly lets talk about the purpose of the method used by you to fetch the topic list (according to your code):

```
Log.i("ERROR ","Topic="+mqttToken.getTopics());
```

The purpose of the above method getTopics() is not to provide you the exhaustive list of topic's available on your MQTT Broker. This method returns the name of the topics associated with your token. And if you go through this [Link](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/IMqttActionListener.html) you will see that the method gets called on the succesfull completion of an operation. Additionally you can have a look over the java doc of the IMqttToken.

May be you can elaborate your use case so that audience can help you with that, fetching all active topics should not be a solution ideally.